# z-index and float not working

Tags: position, css-float, z-index

so I have 4 divs I'm layering with z-indexs here, and am positioning with float and align left, two of them work and two of them don't.  It's important for me to keep the position:relative, but I've been looking over the html to make sure there isn't any inconsistencies, and I just cant find anything, I'm looking for another pair of eyes to pick up what I'm missing here.

http://jsfiddle.net/xCkX7/14/

I have it posted here, it should ultimately look like a stack, all four sitting on top of another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm try this

http://jsfiddle.net/p4Hzb/

relative positions not work for me.

Comment: hmm, they should work, cause they work for the 1st two and the 2nd two, just not sure why they're separated in to pairs.